# how to install virtualbox 5.1

Tags: virtualbox, downloads

I'm trying to install VirtualBox 5.1

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package virtualbox-5.1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-i386.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:2
E: Package 'virtualbox-5.1' has no installation candidate
```

What's happening?

Comment: On which Ubuntu release are you? Does it have to be Virtual Box 5.1 or is a version from the 4.x branch fine?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the link below. This will solve your problem. I have done same step on yesterday. Please also tell version of OS.

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and insert below line in it

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib
```

then run command `sudo apt-get update`

then below command

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential virtualbox-5.1 dkms
```

then follow below link

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/running-virtual-machines-with-virtualbox-5.1-on-a-headless-ubuntu-16.04-lts-server/